# XNA -Install on non admin PC

Tags: installation, xna, portability

I am using XNA 4.0. Is there any way how to install and run an XNA games on a pc that doesn't have administrative rights? (.Net XNA framework is not installed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by 'pc that doesn't have administrative rights', but if I understand your question, you want the redistributable:

[XNA 4.0 Framework Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20914)

You just need to check if the framework is installed when you install the game, and if it's not, just install the file from the page above.

Comment: It means that when I try to install the XNA 4.0 Framework Redistributable the pc gives an error that to install one needs administrative rights. This pc is a school computer and I need to install games for thesis research

Comment: Just right click on the installer and choose `Run as Administrator`

Comment: Well, if you have access to the source code, you can copy the XNA dlls into the game directory, and replace your references to the framework with them. Otherwise, you can try to contact your administrator and see if they can lift whatever restrictions that are in place for you temporarily. Finally, if nothing else works, you could do this part of your research at home. ;)